# Why does subtracting a negative 8-bit value from the 9-bit pattern 100000000 give the magnitude?

Tags: c, twos-complement

My textbook provides the following explanation for the two's complement method for signed integers:

> We’ll discuss this method as it applies to a 1-byte value. In that
> context, the values 0 through 127 are represented by the last 7 bits,
> with the high-order bit set to 0. So far, that’s the same as the
> sign-magnitude method. Also, if the high-order bit is 1, the value is
> negative. The difference comes in determining the value of that
> negative number. Subtract the bit-pattern
> for a negative number from the 9-bit pattern 100000000 (256 as
> expressed in binary), and
> the result is the magnitude of the value.

None of this makes any sense to me. Typical processors use octets (8-bit bytes). What does it mean by subtracting the 8-bit byte from the 9-bit byte?

Comment: There's a lot more information **[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)**

Comment: This has nothing to do with C in particular though.
The idea of the two complement method is being able to write signed numbers depending on the first bit. for example if your byte is 11111111 it means that it's negative, on the contrary, if it's 01111111, it would be positive. Read more about it on the link provided above by @user3386109

Comment: By "subtract" they mean the normal definition of the word in mathematics ... not sure what you are confused about.  E.g. 256 - 251 = 5,  so -5 in two's complement is the same representation as +251

Comment: It's just normal arithmetic. The result of subtracting the 8-bit value from the 9-bit value is going to fit in 8 bits again.

Comment: There's no "9 bit byte" involved

Comment: @melpomene can you please illustrate this?

Comment: @ThePointer Why don't you just work through an example? I don't understand what you're confused about.

Comment: @melpomene  My book says 100000000−10000000 = 10000000, which is mathematically false. This is where my confusion lies.

Comment: Looks correct to me. What do you think it should be?

Comment: @ThePointer It's mathematically true, as long as you understand that those are binary numbers, not decimal numbers.

Comment: @user3386109 I am not aware of how to subtract binary numbers. I suspect this is the problem.

Comment: Yep, understanding [binary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Counting_in_binary) and [binary arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Binary_arithmetic) is the first step.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, for efficient computation, you want to have the same operations (addition, subtraction, etc.) to be performed the same way, regardless of the sign. So first, consider the case of unsigned bytes.

With 8 bits, you can represent any value between 0-255. Addition and subtraction work the same way as usual (modulo 256), and everything is fine.

Now, imagine that when you are at 127, incrementing by 1 gives you -128. We're still counting modulo 256, but the top 128 numbers have shifted by 256. Now, let's examine addition:
10 + (-5) = 10 + 251 (unsigned) = 261 = 5 (modulo 255).

Everything works as expected. So, in our new representation, -128 is 127 + 1, which is 01111111 + 1 which is 10000000. -1 will be 11111111. I hope I've helped.

Answer (score 1):

You have 1 byte (8 digit number with each digit being a 0 or a 1)

2's complement works by looking at the first digit

```
10010011
^ this one
```

If it's a 0, then the number is positive and you can continue to convert binary to decimal normally.

If it's 1, then it's negative. Convert it normally (`bin(10010011) = 147`) and THEN subtract 256 (`147 - 256 = -109`), and there is your 2's complement number.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense. My book gives the following example: 100000000−10000000 = 10000000. This is mathematically false, though.

Comment: @ThePointer Glad I could help. If you consider it an answer then go ahead and click the green check mark ;)

Comment: @ThePointer-- it is not mathematically false; it is binary subtraction.

Comment: @DavidBowling This must be where my misunderstanding lies. Thanks, David.

Answer (score 0):

My memory about two's complement says:

> "Flip the bits plus one"

Indeed, the following makes a number negative:

```
int i, j= 127;
i = (~j)+1;
printf ("%d\n",i); // prints -127
```